# Checking the password of a MS Word document(docx) using Python

Tags: python, ms-word, passwords, docx, password-recovery

I'm trying to write a program in python(2.7) to find a password of a MS word(docx) document. 
What I need is to find a way to check whether the given password matches with the document's password, and it should check it fast.

**Which module/way can I use to check whether a specific password matches with a MS-Word document's password?**

Comment: I see you used the `password-recovery` tag. If you're trying to brute-force a protected `.docx` file, see [this](http://opensourcehacker.com/2011/09/23/unprotecting-microsoft-word-docx-document/).

Comment: I guess that method only works with files that require a password to be edited. But I need a password to open the ENCRYPTED file, so it won't work.

Comment: I very much doubt there's any existing Python module to do this. If you happen to know the encryption mechanism, you might get some pointers if you include that in the question.

Comment: I guess there are some modules to extract information from docx files. If so, there also might be some way to open protected files.